# javaFx set splitpane size to wrap tableview

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

My requirement is displaying a varying number of Rows in a tabelView, where each row contains a label column and a second colum,n with either a textBox, comboBox, richtext or datePicker.

The user may enter some of the values and start a search via a button, displaying the result sint he bottom half of the splitPane.

This table is displayed in a vertical splitPane like this:

```
Name    |    txtName
date    |    datepickerDate
gender  |    cmbGender
----------------------------

Results will be shown here
```

The number of rows of the top-table may vary from 1 to 20+.

I have fixed the maximum splitPane size to be 50%-50% distributed, if the table requires more space than 50% of the window, the user needs to scroll.

What i need is a possibility to, at runtime, know how much space the table actually needs. this is dependent on font-size and contents of the cells (eg.: a richtext-control is slightly larger than a textbox) is there a way to know the actuall space the tableview is going to need?

All question i found here relate to fitting the tableview to the window-size, i need it the other way round, i need to place the SplitPane separator where the table ends

Thanks in advance,

BillDoor

Comment: I believe you could use ColumnConstraints to set the percentWidth and Height maybe?

Comment: the problem is, that I do not know what 100% will be - it is about getting the combined height of all rows before they are displayed